# VLC Windows Command Line

Tags: vlc, command-line-tool

I'm currently trying to make a script that loop over 4 videos, lets say video1.avi to video4.avi.

And when I have an intervention I would like to stop the loop and to play video2.avi, then at the end, take back the loop.

I'd like to know if there is a way to do this with VLC and command line param.

Here is the command line I wrote, but it seem to keep the hand ...

```bsh
vlc.exe --started-from-file --repeat --playlist-enqueue --fullscreen 
video1.avi video2.avi video3.avi video4.avi
```

Thanks

Comment: Keep the hand? an intervention? Please share more details, I don't get it

Comment: When I start the script it looks like that it keeps the hand, I mean I can't ask the script to play another video at a specified moment.